# OpenIddict, after restarting auth server the tokens are invalidated

Tags: oauth, jwt, openid-connect, openiddict

I have the following set up: Authorization server (.NET 6 with MVC, port 7000), Client (.NET 6 with MVC, port 7001), Resource Server (.NET 6 API, port 7002).

Authorization server set up:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
   .AddGoogle(options =>
   {
       options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["ClientId"];
       options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["ClientSecret"];
   });

builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = Claims.Name;
    options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = Claims.Subject;
    options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = Claims.Role;
    options.ClaimsIdentity.EmailClaimType = Claims.Email;

    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
});

builder.Services.AddOpenIddict()
    .AddCore(options =>
    {
        options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
                .UseDbContext<AuthorizationContext>();
    })
    .AddServer(options =>
    {
        options.SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("/connect/authorize")
                .SetLogoutEndpointUris("/connect/logout")
                .SetTokenEndpointUris("/connect/token")
                .SetUserinfoEndpointUris("/connect/userinfo")
                .SetIntrospectionEndpointUris("/connect/introspect");

        options.RegisterScopes(Scopes.Email, Scopes.Profile, Scopes.Roles);

        options.AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow();

        options.AddDevelopmentEncryptionCertificate()
                .AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();

        options.UseAspNetCore()
                .EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough()
                .EnableLogoutEndpointPassthrough()
                .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough()
                .EnableUserinfoEndpointPassthrough()
                .EnableStatusCodePagesIntegration();
    })
    .AddValidation(options =>
    {
        options.UseLocalServer();

        options.UseAspNetCore();
    });

builder.Services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
```

The seeded clients:

```
            await manager.CreateAsync(new OpenIddictApplicationDescriptor
            {
                ClientId = "mvc",
                ClientSecret = "901564A5-E7FE-42CB-B10D-61EF6A8F3654",
                ConsentType = ConsentTypes.Explicit,
                DisplayName = "MVC client application",
                PostLogoutRedirectUris =
                {
                    new Uri("https://localhost:7001/signout-callback-oidc")
                },
                    RedirectUris =
                {
                    new Uri("https://localhost:7001/signin-oidc")
                },
                    Permissions =
                {
                    Permissions.Endpoints.Authorization,
                    Permissions.Endpoints.Logout,
                    Permissions.Endpoints.Token,
                    Permissions.GrantTypes.AuthorizationCode,
                    Permissions.GrantTypes.RefreshToken,
                    Permissions.ResponseTypes.Code,
                    Permissions.Scopes.Email,
                    Permissions.Scopes.Profile,
                    Permissions.Scopes.Roles,
                    Permissions.Prefixes.Scope + "api1"
                },
                    Requirements =
                {
                    Requirements.Features.ProofKeyForCodeExchange
                }
            });

            // resource server
            if (await manager.FindByClientIdAsync("resource_server_1") == null)
            {
                var descriptor = new OpenIddictApplicationDescriptor
                {
                    ClientId = "resource_server_1",
                    ClientSecret = "846B62D0-DEF9-4215-A99D-86E6B8DAB342",
                    Permissions =
                        {
                            Permissions.Endpoints.Introspection
                        }
                };

                await manager.CreateAsync(descriptor);
            }
```

Client config:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/login";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(50);
    options.SlidingExpiration = false;
})
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    options.ClientId = "mvc";
    options.ClientSecret = "901564A5-E7FE-42CB-B10D-61EF6A8F3654";

    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    options.SaveTokens = true;

    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
    options.AuthenticationMethod = OpenIdConnectRedirectBehavior.RedirectGet;

    options.Authority = "https://localhost:7000/";

    options.Scope.Add("email");
    options.Scope.Add("roles");
    options.Scope.Add("api1");

    options.MapInboundClaims = false;

    options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
    options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";
});
```

Resource Server config:

```
builder.Services.AddOpenIddict()
    .AddValidation(options =>
    {
        options.SetIssuer("https://localhost:7000/");
        options.AddAudiences("resource_server_1");

        options.UseIntrospection()
               .SetClientId("resource_server_1")
               .SetClientSecret("846B62D0-DEF9-4215-A99D-86E6B8DAB342");

        options.UseSystemNetHttp();

        options.UseAspNetCore();
    });

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

This is how the client makes request to resource server:

```
    [Authorize, HttpPost("~/")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var token = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The access token cannot be found in the authentication ticket. " +
                                                "Make sure that SaveTokens is set to true in the OIDC options.");
        }

        using var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

        using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://localhost:7002/api/message");
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

        using var response = await client.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        return View("Home", model: await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    }
```

The problem is following when I set up those 3 instances (auth server, client, resource server) and I am NOT authenticated in the client (no cookies). I can authenticate on the client (and therefore on auth server). Then I make the request from the client to the resource server and it returns `200`.

But then I stop all 3 instances and try to do it again.

At that time I'm already authenticated in the client (cookies) and can extract token (FYI the tokens are the same between requests before stopping instances and after). But this token is invalid and the response code from the resource server is `401`.

On the resource server logs I can see the following logs: "`OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore was not authenticated. Failure message: An error occurred while authenticating the current request`", and "`invalid_token, the specified token is invalid`"

**The question**: is it expected behavior? I assume the reason is that data protection changed key ring or something like that. If it is expected - then how to do redeploys without reauthenticating all the users?

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure the problem is with this line

```
    options.AddDevelopmentEncryptionCertificate()
            .AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();
```

Those certificates (keys) are changed when you restart the application. You need to have production encryption/signing keys in place.

See options.AddEncryptionKey and options.AddSigningKey

Key can be created like this

```
var rsa = RSA.Create(2048);
var key = new RsaSecurityKey(rsa);
```

You can get the XML for the key and save it somewhere PRIVATE

```
var xml = key.Rsa.ToXmlString(true);
```

When you start the application, you load the key using the XML

```
var rsa = RSA.Create();
rsa.FromXmlString(xml);
```

Then you add the key to openiddict

```
options.AddEncryptionKey(rsa);
options.AddSigningKey(rsa);
```

You may also want to use the following methods instead

- options.AddEncryptionCredentials
- options.AddSigningCredentials
- options.AddEncryptionCertificate
- options.AddSigningCertificate

It depends of what you have available.

Comment: is it ok using the same key for the both purposes (encryption and signing)?

Comment: @anatol from the doc 

https://documentation.openiddict.com/configuration/encryption-and-signing-credentials.html

In production, it is recommended to use two RSA certificates, distinct from the certificate(s) used for HTTPS: one for encryption, one for signing. Certificates can be generated and self-signed locally using the .NET Core CertificateRequest API:

Comment: thanks, but could you cite this recommendation or point it out? I saw that doc but didn't find there this info (I mean the info about different keys for signing and encryption)